# find filename and treat it like a variable

Tags: python, file, xslt, csv, replace

I have some code like this :

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import os
import sys

# Varibale name

g = 'Fox_Crime20130927092830.xls'
# This code is for transforming xls to csv, but it's external script calling in python
shell1 = 'xls2csv -x $g -s cp1252 -d utf-8 > FOX.csv'
os.system(shell1)
```

How can I read file name in directory, and treat file like variable, then call it in external script to execute?
In variable like:

```
g = 'filename'
```

Can you give me some solution, or advice for this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`str.format`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=str.format#str.format) to insert the contents of a variable into a string.

```
g = 'Fox_Crime20130927092830.xls'
shell1 = 'xls2csv -x {} -s cp1252 -d utf-8 > FOX.csv'.format(g)
print shell1
```

Here, the `{}` in the string will be replaced by the contents of `g`.

Result:

```
xls2csv -x Fox_Crime20130927092830.xls -s cp1252 -d utf-8 > FOX.csv
```

You could also just compose the string manually, but this isn't as nice looking.

```
g = 'Fox_Crime20130927092830.xls'
shell1 = 'xls2csv -x ' + g + ' -s cp1252 -d utf-8 > FOX.csv'
print shell1
```

Answer (score 0):

The above answer using .format is cleaner, but you can also use the scanf syntax

```
g = 'Fox_Crime20130927092830.xls'
shell1 = 'xls2csv -x %s -s cp1252 -d utf-8 > FOX.csv'%(g)
print shell1
```